# How to assign to new row in Pandas.Series with multiindexing?

Tags: pandas

I uses to be able to assign to a series like so:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series()["aaa"]= True        # regular indexing
pd.Series().loc["aaa"]= True        # regular indexing
pd.Series()[("aaa",123)]= True  # Multi indexing
pd.Series().loc[("aaa",123)]= True  # Multi indexing
```

but in pandas 24.0 and up, both of:

```
pd.Series()[("aaa",123)]= True
pd.Series().loc[("aaa",123)]= True
```

gives me:

```
KeyError: u"None of [Index([u'aaa', 1], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

So -- how can I assign to a series using multi-indexing in pandas 0.24.1?

Update:---------
Active bug reference: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25290#issuecomment-463206942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First initialize an empty `MultiIndex` of the correct dimension and then it will work:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[], []], codes=[[], []])
s = pd.Series(index=idx)
s.loc[("aaa",123)]= True

print(s)
#aaa  123    True
#dtype: bool
```